# Relation between $SL(2,R)$ and $U(1)$ symmetry

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, definition, action, invariants

I have an action that I have proven to be invariant under an $SL(2,R)$ symmetry. But I actually want my action to be invariant under an $U(1)$ symmetry (because i know that for the system I am studying a conserved number of particles is associated with an $U(1)$ symmetry), I think this is implied by the $SL(2,R)$ symmetry but I am not very sure so I wanted to check my reasoning here :).

So my action is invariant under the following transformation $\phi \rightarrow \frac{a \phi +b}{c\phi + d}$ with $ad - bc = 1$. If I now choose a subgroup with $a = d = \cos(\alpha)$ and $b = -c = \sin(\alpha)$ then $U(1)$ invariance is implied as $\frac{\cos(\alpha) \phi +\sin(\alpha)}{-\sin(\alpha)\phi + \cos(\alpha)}$ = $\frac{\cos(\alpha + 2\pi) \phi +\sin(\alpha + 2\pi)}{-\sin(\alpha + 2\pi)\phi + \cos(\alpha + 2\pi)}$.

Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ comprises all $2\times 2$ matrices with unit determinant. On the other hand ${\rm U}(1)$ can be identified with the group of rotation matrices in two-dimensions. In turn that would be the connected component with the identity of the orthogonal group in two-dimensions. The two-dimensional orthogonal group can be characterized to be the group of matrices obeying $M^TM =1$. The condition of being connected to the identity in turn restricts these matrices to $\det M=1$.

So we can see that the rotation matrices in two-dimensions (elements of ${\rm SO}(2)\simeq {\rm U}(1)$) are only a special class of the elements of ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.  So indeed if you have established ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ symmetry of an action, you also get ${\rm U}(1)$ symmetry that comes about by restricting to a subgroup.

This is essentially just one tiny bit more abstract version of what you have said yourself. Matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha & \sin\alpha\\ -\sin\alpha &\cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}\in {\rm SO}(2)\simeq {\rm U}(1)$$

are just a special case of matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix}a &b\\ c& d\end{pmatrix}\in {\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{R}),\quad ad-bc=1.$$